# What determines what algorithms are available to OpenSSH?

Tags: linux, openssh, openssl, algorithm

Is the version of OpenSSH or the version of OpenSSL (or a combination of the two) that is installed on a given system what determines which Ciphers, KexAlgorithms, and MACs are available to be configured for use?

Background: We have a legacy process that is using SSH/SFTP to exchange data between an outside organization and ours.  The outside organization is going to begin enforcing the use of stronger crytographic algorithms.  No surprise, the  instance of either OpenSSH or OpenSSL installed on our end is not up to snuff.

Trying to figure out where I would need to look to determine what minimum level I need to make this work in the short term.  What version of which package would carry a given algorithm?

Comment: OpenSSH can be built with OpenSSL support or without.  Check if your version depends on `libssl` or similar, which would indicate it's built with OpenSSL.

Comment: i see libcrypto, but not libssl specifically

Comment: @Erik libcrypto is the relevant library from OpenSSL that OpenSSH links against.  It just uses the cryptographic functions, not the TLS implementation.

Comment: then from that, i'm assuming then that i have to at least update openssl, but possibly also openssh in order to make use of algorithms included in the newer version of openssl  ||  then an off-shoot of of my original question... how do i determine what Ciphers, KexAlgorithms, and MACs will be available in a given version of openssl?

Comment: @Erik - That depends on how OpenSSL was built.

Comment: Any specific reason to not just use the currently available _latest_ version?

Comment: corporate bureaucracy :P  ...seriously though, in my mind, no... but, i'm working with a legacy system and customers who are hesitant to do anything but the bare minimum to get it to work.  if it so happens that the minimum versions of these packages or only a handful of versions back from most recent, then i would push to go to the most recent.  but the burden of proof is on me to find that out.